# How to marshalling struct in C# for SendMessage

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, sendmessage

I defined two structs (one in another) as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 1)]
public struct tagRCV_FILE_HEADEx
{                      
    public int m_dwLen;                                     
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 260)]
    public byte[] m_szFileName;                        
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 1)]
public struct tagRCV_DATA
{
    public int m_nPacketNum;                                        
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public tagRCV_FILE_HEADEx m_File;                                 
}
```

Here's how I initialized:

```
tagRCV_DATA rcv_data = new tagRCV_DATA ();
rcv_data.m_File = new tagRCV_FILE_HEADEx();
rcv_data.m_File.m_szFileName = new byte[260];    
rcv_data.m_nPacketNum = 1;
```

and here's how I did marshalling and call SendMessage:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam); 

// let's say hwnd, Msg and RCV_REPORT are known parameters
IntPtr lParam = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(rcv_data));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(rcv_data,lParam, false);
SendMessage(hwnd, Msg, RCV_REPORT, lParam);
Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, rcv_data);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal (lParam);
```

It crashed when I ran it. Can anyone spot anything I did wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When it crashed, did it give you an error?

Comment: No error. Just crashed silently. If I commented out the SendMessage statement, then no crash. So this has something to do with the SendMessage.

Comment: The 3rd argument is IntPtr, not int.  You cannot send a pointer to a window owned by another process.  A pointer is only valid inside the process that created it.  The app that owns the window will bomb with an access violation when it tries to dereference the pointer.  A workaround is using WM_COPYDATA or allocating memory in the target process with VirtualAllocEx().

Comment: @Hans Passant I changed the third argument to IntPtr, it still crashes. I tried the generic SendMessage  [link]("http://www.andreas-reiff.de/2011/06/generic-wrapper-for-sendmessage-calls-in-c-through-reflection/#comment-77440") by Andreas Reiff  which uses VirtualAllocEx, but the result is the same. I want to make sure my struct init is doing right.  One more thing, when I assigned value to the rcv_data.m_File.m_szFileName, I did this: string name = "somename"; System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name.ToCharArray(), 0, name.Length, rcv_data.m_File.m_szFileName, 0); Am I doing it right?

Comment: I would suggest trapping the exception when calling the PtrToStructure - using try and catch - this will at least tell you what is going on.